# why transaction-type="JTA" cause "WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread"?

Tags: java, openjpa, persistence.xml, apache-tomee

At my persistence.xml when I change from

```
transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"
```

to

```
transaction-type="JTA"
```

i get this error:

```
WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread

viewId=/pages/login.xhtml
location=/home/jakub/Projekty/Collv2/build/web/pages/login.xhtml
phaseId=RESTORE_VIEW(1)

Caused by:
javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException - WebBeans context with scope type annotation @RequestScoped does not exist within current thread
at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:351)
```

I'm using OpenJPA at TomEE server